# Dispatch not sending the action to the reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a react redux app and I am having an issue with dispatching the action to the reducer. This is what I have in my actions.js

```
import GetDataFromAPIs from "../utils/api-data";
export const UPDATE_DATA = 'UPDATE_DATA';

export const updateData = async => {
    const newData = await GetDataFromAPIs();

    return{
        type: UPDATE_DATA, 
        payload: newData
    };
};
```

and this is how I am calling **updateData** from index.js:

```
const menuStore = createStore(MyReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
menuStore.dispatch(applyMiddleware(thunk)(updateData));
```

I can step through the actions.js but I don't see menuStore.dispatch sending the action to the reducer. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add the reducer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using thunk middleware you need to pass  the 'thunk' to the dispatch function.
First, the thunk need some modification. As the docs say [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

> A thunk is a function that wraps an expression to delay its evaluation

Therefore need to change the thunk as below.

```
export const updateData = async (dispatch)=> {
   const newData = await GetDataFromAPIs();

   dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_DATA, 
      payload: newData
    });
};
```

Now pass this thunk to the `store.dispatch()` function.

```
menuStore.dispatch(updateData);
```

Comment: Great! Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

- If using thunk, then your action needs to return a function. The funtion will take dispatch as an argument which will be used to dispatch actions based on api response.
- While calling dispatch you need not use middleware.
- Also the action needs to be called in the dispatch `menuStore.dispatch(updateData())` not just passing reference

```js
export const updateData = inputData => async dispatch => {
    const newData = await GetDataFromAPIs();
    dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_DATA,
        payload: newData
    })
};
```

**Usage**

```js
menuStore.dispatch(updateData())
```

Comment: menuStore.dispatch(updateData()) is throwing this error: "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions"